# PostgreSQL: manipulate binary data - change last byte with SQL command

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10, bytea

In a PostgreSQL table  I have a column `file_bytes` which has the data type *bytea*.

I am looking for a simple SQL statement to manipulate only the last byte of the content of this column.

Comment: `set_byte()`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=82693359a8e2716ba271e80d52a40fbb)

```
UPDATE test 
SET file_bytes = overlay(file_bytes placing 'X'::bytea from octet_length(file_bytes));
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html

`octet_length()` gives the number of bytes of binary data. `overlay()` allows to rewrite data from a certain position.